# connect to oracle database in Load Runner

Tags: oracle, performance, loadrunner

I use LoadRunner 12.5 as performance test tools.
I want to add connection string in my script

```
lr_db_connect ("Stepname=Connect",
"CONNECTIONSTRING=PROVIDER=ORAOLEDB.ORACLE; Password = tst_t; Persist Security info=true; User ID = tst_t; Data Source = tst; Server = 1.1.1.1:11 ",
"Connectionname=OracleDB",
"Connectiontype=OLEDB",
LAST);
```

but I have error :

```
vuser_init.c(3): DB Connection "Connect" started ... Wait ....
vuser_init.c(3): Error: DB Connection failed {"ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified"}
vuser_init.c(3): Error: DB Connection failed {"Connect"}
Abort was called from an action.
```

Answer (score 0):

USE OCI or ODBC, both supported interfaces.   If you want to go the OleDB route consider the Advanced documentation for a Visual Studio virtual user